# Loading and using resources C

Tags: c, windows, embedded-resource

I know, this question is very useless, because there microsoft docs etc.
But I just don't get it.
I am trying to load a custom cursor using the SetSytemCursor function.
I already added it to the resource file, and it's defined as **CustomCursor CURSOR 9** in the resource1.h header file.
I tried a variety of ways to load the file, but none worked. Here is my current code:
(NOTE: This is a function that is called in main. My project uses multiple source files.)

```
#include "resource1.h"
void changeCursorPayload() {
HRSRC hResource = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(CustomCursor), RT_CURSOR);
if (hResource)
{
    HGLOBAL hLoadedResource = LoadResource(NULL, hResource);
    if (hLoadedResource)
    {
        LPVOID pLockedProcedure = LockResource(hLoadedResource);
        if (pLockedProcedure)
        {
            DWORD dwResourceSize = SizeofResource(NULL, hResource);
            if (0 != dwResourceSize)
            {
                HINSTANCE hInstance;

                HCURSOR cursor = (HCURSOR)LoadCursor(NULL, CustomCursor);
                ////Setup a loop to enable one cursor globally.
                for (int cursorStyle = 32512; cursorStyle < 32640; cursorStyle++)
                    SetSystemCursor(cursor, 32512);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried using bin2c (https://sourceforge.net/projects/bin2c/) which will generate a C source file of the cursor, but I have no idea how to implement that. The source file generated is:

```
const long int cursor_cur_size = 4286;
const unsigned char cursor_cur[4286] = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x20, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, etc..
};
```

If someone can help me and show me how to load icons and cursors from resource files, that'd be great.

EDIT:
Compile time warnings:

```
In file included from Payloads/ChangeCursor.c:3,
             from Payloads/payloads.h:13,
             from main.h:14,
             from main.c:21:
Payloads/ChangeCursor.c: In function 'changeCursorPayload':
Payloads/../resource1.h:5:41: warning: passing argument 2 of 'LoadCursorA' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    5 | #define CustomCursor                    9
      |                                         ^
      |                                         |
      |                                         int
Payloads/ChangeCursor.c:294:64: note: in expansion of macro 'CustomCursor'
  294 |                     HCURSOR cursor = (HCURSOR)LoadCursor(NULL, CustomCursor);
      |                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\windows.h:72,
                 from c:\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\rpc.h:16,
                 from c:\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wtypesbase.h:7,
                 from c:\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\shlobj.h:9,
                 from main.c:19:
c:\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\winuser.h:3954:68: note: expected 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char *'} but argument is of type 'int'
 3954 |   WINUSERAPI HCURSOR WINAPI LoadCursorA(HINSTANCE hInstance,LPCSTR lpCursorName);
      |                                                             ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: *but none worked*. Do you know exactly where it went wrong? If you debug, are any of the calls you making returning NULL? Or is there a different issue?

Comment: The program just exits with no errors when I compile and run. I cannot debug the application. My IDE is visual studio, and the compiler returns a buch of errors, so I have to compile with gcc. I think it returns all these errors because I am writing C code in a C++ console application

Comment: That's what I would expect it to do, based upon your logic, if any one of the functions returned NULL. I'm asking if you've done any debugging to narrow it down to which function may have returned NULL, or if you know it exited for any other reason.

Comment: As I said, I cannot perform any debugging. The application did not end with any exit codes. I just added GetLastError,  after SetSystemCursor (Outside the for loop), and it did not return anything

Comment: Yes, you can perform debugging. Debugging isn't just about seeing a program exist code. You can set breakpoints, or minimally you can add some kind of log output or message boxes to indicate where you saw a NULL return. You can also return a different exit code depending upon which function returns NULL. Currently, your program simply returns the same way, with no special code, when any function returns NULL.

Comment: Ok gotcha, I used gdb. Totally forgot about that.
`Starting program: C:\Users\user\source\repos\Test malware\Test malware\runme.exe

[New Thread 7756.0x19c8]

[New Thread 7756.0x2ec4]

[New Thread 7756.0x18dc]

[New Thread 7756.0x2674]
warning: 
Can not parse XML library list; XML support was disabled at compile time

[Thread 7756.0x18dc exited with code 0]

[Thread 7756.0x2ec4 exited with code 0]

[Thread 7756.0x2674 exited with code 0]

[Inferior 1 (process 7756) exited normally]`

Comment: At first you said the program ran but didn't do what you expected (only exited). Now you're saying you have compile errors?

Comment: Not errors, warnings. The code still compiles and runs

Comment: I see, yes, sorry about that. You should address the warnings. For example, if you look up the documentation for `LoadCursor`, the second argument needs the *name* of the cursor. You can also use `MAKEINTRESOURCE` here. So in your case, it should be `MAKEINTRESOURCE(CustomCursor)` for the second argument, not `CustomCursor`. You should address the other warnings as well. Check the documentation for those functions.

Comment: Okay, MAKEINTRESOURCE removed all the errors. Although the program is still not changing the cursor.
On the documentation for LoadCursor it says that the first argument must be NULL for a Win32 cursor. I don't want that, so I have to change the hInstance. The file is included in my file, so what would I set hInstance to? (DOCS): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms911499(v=msdn.10)

Comment: @lurker I tried
HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

HCURSOR cursor = (HCURSOR)LoadCursor(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(CustomCursor));

Comment: You mean you got rid of the warnings (not errors). Still don't know which of your functions is returning NULL, or if one of them is.

Comment: There are no errors, and when running the application with gdb, it exits normally
I think im not calling something correctly, which will lead the whole block of code to not be executed

Comment: At the moment I am only calling the cursor function in main. And I don't know how to properly debug C applications, so Idk how to know if the function returns NULL.

Comment: @lurker do you have any idea what im doing wrong? I still can't seem to fix the problem

Comment: I'd recommend reading the documentation for the functions you're using. For example, the documentation for [`SetSystemCursor(hcur, id)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setsystemcursor) states: *The system destroys `hcur `by calling the `DestroyCursor` function. Therefore, **`hcur` cannot be a cursor loaded using the `LoadCursor` function.** To specify a cursor loaded from a resource, copy the cursor using the `CopyCursor` function, then pass the copy to `SetSystemCursor`.*

Comment: Oh, right, thanks. I was so focused on the LoadCursor that I completely forgot to look at SetSytstemCursor again.